# JTextArea won't allow for text to be typed in

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I've read up on the other questions about JTextArea and moved the setVisible(true) to the bottom, but my JTextArea still will not let me display text. My code is below, it is the constructor of a class that extends JPanel, it won't show anything when I type into the JTextArea. The JTextArea appears in the middle, called "newText." Thank you for your help!

```
EditScreen(TaskMaster taskMaster, Task toEdit){
        this.taskMaster = taskMaster;
        editingTask = toEdit;
        textAreaShading = new Color(10, 20, 20, 20);
        initBackground();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(500,500));
        this.setBackground(background); //this might not be initializedset

        topToolbar = new JPanel();
        topToolbar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)); 
        topToolbar.setOpaque(false);
        topToolbar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topToolbar, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        category = new JLabel("Choose type:");
        categories = new JComboBox(catS);
        date = new JTextField(10);
        topToolbar.add(category);
        topToolbar.add(categories);
        topToolbar.add(new JLabel("Due Date:"));
        topToolbar.add(date);


        textPanel = new JPanel();
        //textPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));  
        textPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));   
        textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
        //textPanel.setOpaque(false);
        textPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        newText = new JTextArea();
        newText.setOpaque(true);
        newText.setBackground(textAreaShading);
        newText.setLineWrap(true);
        newText.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
        textPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, newText);


        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,2,0)); 
        bottomPanel.setOpaque(false);
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        priority = new JComboBox(priorityS); 
        cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        save = new JButton("Save");
        bottomPanel.add(new JLabel("Choose Priority:"));
        bottomPanel.add(priority);
        bottomPanel.add(cancel);
        bottomPanel.add(save);


        //set layout and size of frame
        this.add(topToolbar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        //screenPanel.add(newText, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        this.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        initListeners();
        initEditingTask();
        this.setVisible(true);
        textPanel.setVisible(true);
        newText.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Try removing  newText.setOpaque(true);

Comment: (1) For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. We cannot reproduce your problem with just a code snippet. (2) Normally, you don't need to call `newText.setVisible(...)` at all.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to avoid that bc the project is very big and I wasn't sure about how to provide a MCE. I will attempt to do so if I can't come across a solution. I was hoping it was a small, quick fix that was escaping my eye!

Comment: Calling `newText.setBackground(textAreaShading)` will make the background very dark according to `textAreaShading` declaration, so if your text is also dark (black?), are you sure you are *able to see* dark text with dark background?

Answer (score 0):

Ok somebody answered my question and then deleted that response so I will post it here, this was not my doing but it was the problem with the program and so here it is!

setLayout(new BorderLayout(500,500)); puts large gaps on that cover the whole are.

Solution: reduce the gaps

setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));

Code Riddle: Completed. Thank you Everyone!